# Best way to send object of array in response grpc

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I want to make response in proto which is something like this in  REST format :

```
response  = {
  "cars":[{'asd':1 , 'date': 1},{'asd':1 , 'date': 1},{'asd':1 , 'date': 1}],
  "houses":[{'asd':1 , 'date':Flexible Savings 1},{'asd':1 , 'date': 1},{'asd':1 , 'date': 1}],
}
```

how I Can write its proto file? And **2ndly** in case I am not sure how many arrays I have to append in responce in that case what is practice  need to be followed in grpc proto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```proto
message Response {
    repeated Thing cars = 1;
    repeated Thing houses = 2;
}
message Thing {
    int32 asd = 1;
    int32 date = 2;
}
```

This may change a little depending on whether the two shapes (cars and houses) are the same, and whether the asd and date are actually integers. You might need a `Car` and `House` message type, and you might want a "timestamp" for "date".

Comment: thanks for answer sir , And can you please guide about If I don't know Number of  arrays need to return ? Like It can be 4,5 ...100 . then ?

Comment: @Ninja context? Maybe you need a `map<string, Something>` where a `Something` *has* a `repeated Thing`?

Comment: Can you sir provide any link etc ?  I am newbie in this so can't understand properly

Comment: @Ninja have you read the schema language overview? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3